# How to Use OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager vs OAuth2AuthorizedClientService

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm implementing an OAuth2 client in Spring Boot 2, using Spring Security 5. I'm unclear how I'm supposed to use [OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.html) vs [OAuth2AuthorizedClientService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2AuthorizedClientService.html). OAuth2AuthorizedClientManger was introduced in 5.2 so it's a newer API, but OAuth2AuthorizedClientService seems like a more polished client interface. I expected `OAuthe2AuthorizedClientService` would be configurable with a `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Importantly, I needed to customize the `OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter` to customize the request sent to the authorization server. That's available on the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` but I can't figure out how to do that from the `OAuthe2AuthorizedClientService`.

My code that registers a OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.

```
  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                               OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService) {

    DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient defaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient = new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();
    defaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(new OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantJWTAssertionRequestEntityConverter());
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
          .clientCredentials(clientCredentialsGrantBuilder -> {

            clientCredentialsGrantBuilder.accessTokenResponseClient(defaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient);
          })
          .build();
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager
        = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, oAuth2AuthorizedClientService);
    ((AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager)authorizedClientManager).setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
    return authorizedClientManager;
  }
```

Comment: What customization do you need to make to the request sent to the authorization server?

Comment: @peater, our auth server uses JWT assertions (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7523) instead of client I'd and client secret

Comment: if you need to send a custom request I think you want to customize `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter`

Comment: That's what `DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient` is.